# Access rights of files from an old laptop's HDD

Tags: hard-drive, file-recovery, password-management

My old laptop died because of battery issues earlier in the year, and I've managed to get the HDD out before trashing it.

I've bought a new laptop and a USB/SATA plug, and I can access and see the old file tree of my old C: drive (now H:)

I'm trying to recover my personal files from C:\Users\$Username.
Unfortunately, I do not have the autorisations, and if I remember my old password I can't remember the name of the laptop (domain controller).

Do you have any way/program which can gain me access rights ?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Other than taking ownership as Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ignacia Vazquez-Abrams, I've got the answer :

Taking ownership as administrator. 
Going to the security pannel of the Folder properties, advanced security settings, and  changing the owner.

Thank you all.